# How do i print whole program runtime output in Gui python

Tags: python, tkinter, stdout

well basically what i am trying to do is that i want to show the output being executed in a graphical interface. 
i have a bash script that i am running using following code

```
from subprocess import call
myscript= call("Myscript.sh", shell=True)
```

Now this Myscript performs some set of tasks. i want to show everything that is happening in output to a graphical interface.
some logic that i was trying to do here is by storing all the output in a string and printing it but it displays the final conlusion and its an integer value! i want all the strings to be printed of myscript working. 
code is as following that i tried :

```
root = Tk()
words=[]

a= call("sh amapt.sh", shell=True)
w = Label(root, text=words.append(a))
w.pack()
print w
root.mainloop()
```

[This is my script output that i want to be displayed in a Gui somewhere as in label or form. i dont know how. im confused please guide me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9eJCH.png)

Answer (score 0):

`call` returns the exit code, which is an integer value. Try `check_output`, which returns the text.

```
from subprocess import check_output

root = Tk()

# to get the error message you need to catch stderr too
a = check_output("sh amapt.sh; exit 0", shell=True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
w = Label(root, text=a)
w.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'Myscript' returned non-zero exit status 255

Now what?

Comment: That means 'Myscript' failed to run correctly. Fix whatever is preventing Myscript from running.

Comment: script is running perfectly and doing its work.

Comment: its fails to run with this check_output

Comment: `call` and `check_output` both pass the work to `Popen`, so if it works in one it should work in the other... I can't really help you with that further without seeing what you are trying to run. [Read the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) and make sure you are passing the variables correctly.

Comment: i have edited my question please do check the image i pasted in question. its the ouput of my script. that is running perfectly with call(myscript). But it fails to run with check_output, it give this error with check_ output  
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'Myscript' returned non-zero exit status 255

Comment: Oh, so you are specifically trying to see an error? Ok, I updated my answer (with code straight from the docs), but I have the feeling that whatever you are doing there is a better way to do it.

Comment: i am trying to get the whole program output to a gui dialog